# How can I install themes on XCode 4.3.2?

Tags: xcode, themes, xcode4.3

How can I install this theme http://simplyhacking.com/spacedust-xcode-theme-for-xcode-4.html on XCode 4.3.2?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Download that Spacedust.dvtcolortheme and save it under:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes
```

It might be that this folder doesn't exist yet if you never copied an existing Colortheme in the preferences of Xcode. In that case: simply create that directory.

Then restart Xcode.

Comment: XCode has been installed in Applications since 4.3.2.

Comment: Well, even since 4.3. And your usersettings will be taken from your homedirectory since 1.0 ;-)

Comment: It might be that this folder doesn't exist yet if you never copied an existing Colortheme in the preferences of Xcode. In that case: simply create that directory.

Comment: I put it into this folder /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes, restart XCode, but it isn't appear in xcode preferences

Comment: Theme has been installed. Thanks!

Comment: The Library folder is hidden by default in Lion so you will need to use Termimal to copy the color theme or show hidden files by typing into Terminal: 'defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE'

Comment: This works fine in 4.4.1. Make sure the files have the correct extension and not, for example, .txt. In Finder preferences, Advanced, turn on "Show all filename extensions" in case the OS is hiding the extension (or just use terminal).

Comment: It took me a little time to figure it out, cause 'Library' is not visible under my folder name, but when I found the carpet and put the themes, it works.
A quicker way to do this: On finder: Go to carpet: /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes

Comment: if closing the ide doesn't work try 'killall Xcode' in the terminal

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add one more little information that after adding the theme to FontAndColorThemes folder and restarting xcode4, go to Fonts & Colors.

you should see it under :

> Preferences -> Fonts & Colors.

select your theme and enjoy the theme.

ref : http://superqichi.com/add-new-theme-to-xcode-4

Answer (score 1):

ThemeInstaller is an easy app for installing themes in Xcode.
Having ThemeInstaller all you need to do is to open an .dvtcolortheme, or go to codethemes.net and press "install" under any of your choice.
In Xcode you need to press "cmd" + "," and there you have all of your installed themes.